# How to retrieve last element from firestore Array in android?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a schema like below in firestore:

[image]

I have document snapshot listener written to fetch the whole array via:

```
// inside snapshot listener
List<String> order_data= (List<String>) documentSnapshot.get("done"); // this returning whole array!
```

**But i want only last element from the done array**. Any help people?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want any data in a document, you have to read the entire document.  There is no avoiding that.

If you already have the contents of a list field in a List object, then you can get the list item in that list using:

```
String last = order_data.get(order_data.size() - 1);
```